# Is there software for transcribing and recognizing musical pitches in an audio recording?

Tags: music

Does GarageBand or any other Mac software make it possible to determine the notes in a musical recording?

It doesn't have to be absolute, and it doesn't even have to guess the rhythm. Determining the intervals would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GarageBand cannot do this. You should investigate the commercial products [Celemony Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/cms/) and [Neuratron AudioScore](http://www.neuratron.com/audioscore.htm).

Also have a look at [Capo](http://supermegaultragroovy.com/products/Capo/) by SuperMegaUltraGroovy. It provides a good method for assisting a person in transcribing by ear.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not in the general case.

This still seems to be a research problem.  One of those areas where commonly available software hasn't (yet?) caught up with musically talented small children.  [MIREX](http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/MIREX_HOME) holds an annual contest.